# Boolean as a parameter/argument?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple HTML5 game and I'm trying to implement an achievement system. My method is creating an Achievement Object with properties such as name, description, condition, etc... So now all I need to do is create different Achievement objects by calling something like: `Achievement.LookARock = new Achievement("Look!  A Rock!", "Mined stone for the first time!", (stone.count == 1), false);`. So now all I have to do is check that the Achievements condition is true. I do that by calling `setInterval`. Here is the code I am using:

```
//Achievements
Achievement.LookARock = new Achievement("Look! A rock!", "Mined stone for the first time.", (stone.count >= 1), false);
Achievement.IGotWood = new Achievement("Haha... I got wood...", "Mined wood for the first time.", (wood.count == 1), false);
Achievement.Stone100 = new Achievement("Stone 100", "Mined 100 stone blocks.", (stone.count == 100), false);
Achievement.Stone500 = new Achievement("Stone 500", "Mined 500 stone blocks.", (stone.count == 500), false);
Achievement.Stone1000 = new Achievement("Stone 1000", "Mined 1000 stone blocks.", (stone.count == 1000), false);
Achievement.FirstCraft = new Achievement("First Craft", "Crafted your first item.", (craftedtools.length == 2), false);
Achievement.Shiny = new Achievement("Oooooo... shiny!", "Mined a diamond!", (diamond_ore.count == 1), false);
Achievement.ICantButter = new Achievement("I can't believe it's not butter!", "Mined gold!", (gold_ore.count == 1), false);
Achievement.IronMan = new Achievement("I am Iron Man...", "Mined metal!", (metal_ore == 1), false);
//Achievement.Level1 = new Achievement("Level 1 Completed!", "Crafted a Diamond Pickaxe!", craftedtools.includes(diamond_pick), false);

/*var achievements = [Achievement.LookARock, 
                    Achievement.IGotWood, 
                    Achievement.Stone100,
                    Achievement.Stone500,
                    Achievement.Stone1000,
                    Achievement.FirstCraft,
                    Achievement.Shiny,
                    Achievement.ICantButter,
                    Achievement.IronMan];*/

function checkAchievement(achievement){

    var condition = achievement.condition;
    var achieved = achievement.achieved;

    if(condition !== false){

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

function checkAchievements(){

    for(var i = 0; i < achievements.length; i++){

        var a = achievements[i];

        if(checkAchievement(a)){

            alert(a.name + "\n" + a.description);

        }

    }

}

function update(){

    try{

        checkAchievements();

    }catch(e){

        console.log(e);

    }

}

changeTool(stone_pick);
makeMineGenerator();

setInterval(update, 50);
```

I know for sure that it is checking the achievement. But the condition is always returning false even when the count is the correct amount. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What "count"?  All that's happening in the code you posted is that you check the value of a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you create achievements is in cause. `(stone.count == 1)` Is evaluated before the call to the Achievement constructor, so that the `condition`property is assigned `false` when the object is created.

You need to build you Achievement object with a function to call when you want to check the achievement.

```
Achievement.LookARock = new Achievement(
  "Look!  A Rock!", 
  "Mined stone for the first time!", 
  function() { 
    return stone.count == 1; 
  }, 
  false
);
```

Then to check the achievement you can use `if (achievement.condition())`.